# Magento 2 checkout loader is stuck

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, error, loader

I've seen this question a couple of times, but i wasn't able to solve my problem.

My checkout page loads fine but the "loader" gif doesn't go away and I can't interact. Usually refreshing the page solves the problem.

At first I thought the problem was with an extension i had installed, but even after disabling it nothing has changed.

I can see some error when the page is stuck, i'll attach them. I don't know JS, so i don't truly understand what they mean.

[image]

Comment: take a look in that js file at line 40. This means that it tries to hide an element that does not exist on the page. Probably your extension is not fully disabled and the JS file is still loaded.

Comment: check proper  error in `system.log` and `exception.log` ...

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski You could be right, this javascript is from a module (but not the one i've disabled). I've contacted who made it and I'll let you know